# jquery remove method on duplicated content

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, twitter-bootstrap

I have a popover dialog using bootstrap popover which populates the content from another div at the bottom of the page.

The html looks like:

**Elements I'm looping through and attaching a popup to:**

```
<sup id="cite_ref-3-0" class="reference bootstrap-footnote" data-original-title="">
  [<a href="#cite_note-3">3</a>]
</sup>
```

**Bottom of the document with references which populates the popup:**

```
<li id="cite_note-1">
    <b><a href="#cite_ref-1-0">^</a> </b> 
    <a target="_blank" href="http://www.guardian.co.uk/music/musicblog/2009/aug/17/major-labels-spotify/">
         "Behind the music: The real reason why the major labels love Spotify"
    </a> 
    <i>The Guardian.</i>  17 August 2009
</li>
```

And I have a jquery function which iterates over all the references on the page, but I can't figure out how to parse the html before populating the popover.  I would like to remove the `<b>` tag and everything inside.

I tried various combinations of .remove("b") on my variable but to not avail.  What am I missing?

```
        $element
            .addClass("bootstrap-footnote")
            .each(function(i,item) {
                var footnote_ref = $("a", this).attr("href");
                var footnote_val = $(footnote_ref).html(); //remove("b")
                var footnote = footnote_val; //remove("b")
                $(item).popover({
                    html: true,
                    title: null,
                    content: footnote,
                    delay: { show: 50, hide: 1500 },
                    //placement: "bottom",
                    trigger: "hover"
                });
            });
```

Comment: yeah. the <b> tag and everything inside it.

Comment: Can't you just do `$('b',this).remove();`

Comment: i tried `$('b',footnote_val).remove();` after initiating the var by the same name, but it does nothing.  FYI, I don't want to remove the <b> tag from the document itself, just when I duplicate it for the popover.

Comment: I updated my question with one step I left out, but aside from being unable to remove the <b> tag the rest of the code works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand what you want now

```
$element.addClass("bootstrap-footnote").each(function(i, item) {        
    var liID = $('a',this).attr('href'); // this is your li's id
    var footnote = $(liID).clone().find('b').remove().end();   // clone the li - remove b

    $(item).popover({
        html: true,
        title: null,
        content: footnote.html(),
        delay: {
            show: 50,
            hide: 1500
        },
        //placement: "bottom",
        trigger: "hover"
    });
});​
```

Comment: close..., oddly, now the only thing being displayed is the thing I'm trying to get rid of. ;-)